# Macro name must be an identifier

Tags: c, macros, identifier

please, tell me what's wrong with this code:

```
// part of main.c

#if have(some_macro)
    printf("Import succeeded!\n");
#else
#   error Import failed!
#endif

// part of utils.h

#define have(macro) defined(macro)
```

If I write just `#if defined(some_macro)` it works.
What's the problem?

Comment: I suppose you have to `#include "utils.h"` first

Comment: Errors are a huge help.

Comment: Also, the preprocessor should have run twice to first insert `defined` instead of `have` and then to evaluate `defined(some_macro)`

Comment: These code snippets are just part of project. I DO include `utils.h` in `main.c`, the error that occurs is in the title of question and my custom message "Import failed!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have anything following `#if` expand to `defined`. That is subject to undefined behavior.

From the C99 Standard (emphasis mine):

> **6.10.1 Conditional inclusion**
>
> ...
>
> 3 Preprocessing directives of the forms

```
 # if *constant-expression new-line group<sub>opt</sub>*
 # elif *constant-expression new-line group<sub>opt</sub>*
```

check whether the controlling constant expression evaluates to nonzero.

> 4 Prior to evaluation, macro invocations in the list of preprocessing tokens that will become the controlling constant expression are replaced (except for those macro names modified by the `defined` unary operator), just as in normal text. **If the token `defined` is generated as a result of this replacement process or use of the `defined` unary operator does not match one of the two specified forms prior to macro replacement, the behavior is undefined**.

Comment: So, I can't return `defined`.

Comment: @R.O.S.S, No, you can't.

Comment: That's some of the features I won't ever understand. This seems to me like not-well-done job.

Comment: @R.O.S.S, you could be right. You have to understand how the preprocessor and compiler work quite a bit to be able come up with a reasonable solution.